# How to change Static HTML iframe tab icon

Tags: facebook, static-html

I am using the [Static HTML: iFrame Tabs](http://apps.facebook.com/static_html_plus/) app to use to design landing pages for several businesses. I have designed the landing page in html and it working fine,but i need to change the Tab's icon,i need put my own icon. please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This application will help you with that
https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=205521576149308

it is the same application with more features including custom icon

Comment: then build your own app: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/